# Atk framework Questions

Tags: php

In employee node i have written like this

```
<?php

  class employee extends atkNode{

      function employee(){
//$this->atkNode("employee");


    $this->atkNode("employee" ,NF_ADD_LINK);


    $this->setTable("newmod1_employee");


$this->add(new atkNumberAttribute("id",AF_AUTOKEY));


$this->add(new atkAttribute("name" ,AF_OBLIGATORY|AF_SEARCHABLE),NULL,10);


$this->add(new atkListAttribute("designation",array('Manager','Junior Scientist ','PHP Programmer','Sap Programmer','Quality Analyist'),AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,40);


$this->add(new atkDateAttribute("date",AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,45);



$this->add(new atkAttribute("location",AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,50);



$this->add(new atkattribute("branch",AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,55);



//$this->add(new  atkManyToOneRelation("designation","newmod1.employee",AF_SEARCHABLE));



$this->add(new atkNumberAttribute("employeecode",AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,60);



$this->add(new atkEmailAttribute("email",AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,65);



  }         
  /*
  public function adminFooter(){
    return nodeSourceUrl("newmod1.employee");
  }*/

 }
```

In department node i have written like this

```
 class department extends atkNode {

//$descriptor_field="[designation]-[destination]";

function department() {

       $this->atkNode("department" ,NF_ADD_LINK);

       $this->setTable("newmod1_department");

       $this->add(new atkNumberAttribute("id",AF_AUTOKEY), NULL,10);

       $this->add(new atkAttribute("name" ,AF_READ_ONLY,AF_OBLIGATORY|AF_SEARCHABLE),NULL,20 );   

       $this->add(new atkAttribute("branch",AF_OBLIGATORY), NULL,30);   

       $this->add(new atkListAttribute("designation",array('Manager','Junior Scientist','PHP Programmer','Sap Programmer','Quality Analyist'),AF_PRIMARY|AF_SEARCHABLE|AF_FORCE_LOAD|AF_OBLIGATORY),NULL,40);



       //$this->addFilter(new atkOneToManyRelation("designation","newmod1.designation","id", AF_OBLIGATORY), "employees"); 

        $this->add(new atkattribute("Salary",AF_TOTAL ) );
    }


  /*
 public function adminFooter(){
    return nodeSourceUrl("newmod1.employee");
 }*/
```

}

I have created a table for this two nodes.I dont know how to use filters and validators for department node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an atkonetomanyrelation between your employee table and your department table

Suggest you post this query on the ATK forum at http://forum.achievo.org/viewforum.php?f=2

Wayne